# bash shell copy the file from one location to another using break and continue

Tags: bash

I have small script to copy the all the files from one directory (SRC) to another directory (DES). This below script is running perfectly.

```
#!/bin/bash

SRC="/home/user/dir1/*"
DES="/home/user/dir2/"

for file in "$SRC"
do
       if [ -f "$file" ]
       then
              cp "$file" "$DES"
              echo "$file -----> file copied"   
       fi
done
```

Now what i am thinking while copying files from one directory to another directory, how to skip the copying file if that file has already exist in (DES) directory with same name of (SRC) directory and continue the remaining file as usual from source to destination?

Here how to i use break and continue looping to perform this action?

Thanks,

Comment: Check for -e filename

Comment: This will only ever copy one file: `/home/user/dir1/*`. No glob expansion is ever performed since you are quoting all the parameters.

Comment: `for file in $SRC` has its own problems, since the value is subject to word splitting. Either set `SRC=/home/user/dir1`, then iterate over `for file in "$SRC"/*`, or use an array to store the expanded list of names: `SRC=(/home/user/dir1/*); for file in "${SRC[@]}"`. There is no good way to store a glob in a variable to expand later.

Comment: Why do you want to use break and continue?  There is no need for them.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use `rsync`:

```
src="/home/user/dir1/"
dst="/home/user/dir2/"
rsync -rav --ignore-existing "${src}" "${dst}"
```

The switch `--ignore-existing` tells `rsync` to skip files which exist at the destination.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just reduce the entire script to a oneliner?

```
cp -n /home/user/dir1/* /home/user/dir2/
```

The `-n` flag (`--no-clobber`) prevents `cp` from overwriting existing files.

If your real situation is more complicated, you can also take a look at `rsync`.